# Django ModelForm submit button not working

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to make a Django ModelForm that retrieves data from my database using the GET method. When I click the submit button nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

HTML doc

```
<form role="form" action="" method="GET" id="form-map" class="form-map form-search">
     <h2>Search Properties</h2>
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
          <input type="submit" action= "" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">
          <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
</form><!-- /#form-map -->
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import StLouisCitySale208
from django.forms import ModelForm, ModelMultipleChoiceField


class StLouisCitySale208Form(ModelForm):
    required_css_class = 'form-group'
    landuse = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='Land use', widget=forms.SelectMultiple, queryset=StLouisCitySale208.objects.values_list('landuse', flat=True).distinct())
    neighborho =forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='Neighborhood',widget=forms.SelectMultiple, queryset=StLouisCitySale208.objects.values_list('neighborho', flat=True).distinct())
    policedist = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='Police district',widget=forms.SelectMultiple,queryset=StLouisCitySale208.objects.values_list('policedist', flat=True).distinct())
    class Meta:
        model = StLouisCitySale208
        fields = ['landuse', 'neighborho', 'policedist', 'precinct20','vacantland', 'ward20', 'zip', 'zoning','asmtimprov', 'asmtland', 'asmttotal', 'frontage', 'landarea','numbldgs', 'numunits']
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import FormView, TemplateView
from .forms import StLouisCitySale208Form

class StLouisCitySale208View(FormView):
    form_class = StLouisCitySale208Form
    template_name = 'maps/StlouiscitySale208.html'
```

maps/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import StLouisCitySale208View, ComingSoonView

app_name = 'maps'

urlpatterns = [
    path("maps/stlouiscitysale208",StLouisCitySale208View.as_view(),name="stlouiscitysale208"),
    path('maps/coming_soon', ComingSoonView.as_view(), name="coming_soon")
]
```

Comment: Please show your view/urls, does the URL not change to include the values from the form inn the querystring?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click to submit button on the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a get method in your class to tell the button what to do.

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
     # <view logic>
    return HttpResponse('result')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/

Comment: I'm certain this is the right answer. I don't know what to put in ('results') to return the GET request.

Comment: Let's break it down.  What do you want to do with the information that you are retrieving?

Comment: I'm making a real estate application. I want the user to be able to query the database and return the results on the same page.

Comment: Are you ok with the whole page refreshing showing the new results?  If not, then you will need to use some JavaScript and ajax, or something equivalent to not do a full page refresh

Comment: That's fine for now. My end goal is to use HTMX to handle the ajax request. At this point my goal it to launch a functioning application as soon as possible.

Comment: Then just return a rerendered page with the new data. Something  like this would work for now:  return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)

Comment: I got it to work! Now my form fields are no longer rendering.

Comment: Everything will have to be on the same page then. For the results part you'll want to do some sort of. If statement in the template, based on if there's anything in your variables or not

Comment: Also, you'll have to return the form in the new context as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245540/discussion-between-brad-and-adam-james).

Answer (score 0):

Your form currently has `method="GET"` which is something you'd use for search, or some other operation which doesn't change the state of the application.

If that's what you want to do, and you're using existing data, through a form, to allow users to query the database, then you'll need to implement a `get` method on the view in order to implement the logic for this. The following should help with the `get()` method for `FormView`;

http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.0/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/#get

It sounds like you're hoping to create objects using your model form, so change that to `method="POST"` and you'll at least allow the application to create your object. There may be more to debug at that point, but you need to start by sending data to the server.

Comment: The form queries values in my Postgres database. Is the GET method suitable in that case?

Comment: @Brad if you're looking to query the database, then like the other answer here says, you'll need to provide a `get()` request on your view which implements the logic for what you want to achieve. In that situation a `method="get"` form will be sufficient.